# What would happed when new(interface{}) in Golang?

Tags: go, interface, new-operator

I'm in a trouble in golang's interface.
the interface{} means any type. but I new(interface{}) in golang. what would happen?
it not equal to a variable whose type is interface{}
and it can't do a assignment in point symbol。

The below is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type S struct{}

func (s S) name() int { return 1 }

func main() {
    var a, b interface{}
    fmt.Println(a == b)
    fmt.Printf("%#v   %#v\n", a, b)

    a = new(interface{ name() int })
    fmt.Println(a == b)
    fmt.Printf("%#v   %#v\n", a, b)

}
```

Comment: *"The new built-in function allocates memory. The first argument is a type, not a value, and the value returned is a pointer to a newly allocated zero value of that type."* - Regardless of whether the type argument is an interface or not, `new`'s behaviour, as stated in the doc, doesn't change.

Comment: *interface{} means any type*.   This is not correct.  A variable of `interface{}` type can store a value of any type, but `interface{}` itself is a specific type.

Answer (score 0):

`new` on any interface type creates a `nil` value of that type and returns a pointer to it. Remember, an interface value is just a struct with two fields: the type, and the underlying value. The type in this case is `interface{}`, the underlying value is `nil`. `new` returns a pointer to the value it creates, so it returns a `*interface{}`. You can check details about it yourself:

https://go.dev/play/p/PdknVrgAWfl

```
i := new(interface{})
fmt.Printf("i: %T, *i: %T\n", i, *i)
v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
fmt.Printf("Val: %#v, Kind: %s, Type: %+v\n", v, v.Kind(), v.Type())

/*
i: *interface {}, *i: <nil>
Val: (*interface {})(0xc000014250), Kind: ptr, Type: *interface {}
*/
```